# Google Webdesigner Removes font paths

Tags: css, html, fonts, google-web-designer

I have to make some html5 ads. I've chosen the Google Webdesigner (GWD) because the ads will be included in google DoubleClick afterwards and GWD has already set up every library for DoubleClick.

Our customer has a special font, that I have to use for the ads.

I included the `@font-face` tag in the header

```
@font-face {
      font-family: Conv_DINLi_;
      src: local(☺), url("assets/fonts/DINLi_.woff") format("woff"), url("assets/fonts/DINLi_.ttf") format("truetype"), url("assets/fonts/DINLi_.svg") format("svg");
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
}
```

and added the converted fonts to the "assets/fonts/ folder.

When I push now "shift"+"enter" to get a preview in the Browser, GWD removes the file paths to the fonts:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kwwf50ou80y6s83/Screenshot%202016-06-28%2009.14.37.png?dl=0

Anyone had this problem so far?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, seems that there is a bug here and was reported, then as a workaround in the meantime the solution is to re-enter by hand, that line which has been deleted by mistake.